# Vundle (plugin for Vim) configuration problem

Tags: command-line, root, configuration, vim, etc

I write the following configuration in my `/etc/vim/vimrc` to run the Vundle plugin.

Why I got this errors?

Vim configuration block that I add:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

I got these errors while running `.vimrc`:

```
root@someone-System-Product-Name:/etc/vim# vim vimrc
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line    6:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line   11:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line   14:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I run `:PluginInstall`, I got the error `'Not an editor command'`.

Comment: Not it is not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the system-wide configuration with user configuration.

The [manual of Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start) suggests adding a script to “your `.vimrc`”, i.e. `~/.vimrc`, particularly adding a link to `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`. Both these files reside in a user’s home directory (`~`) and do not affect other users.

However, if you put the script (including the link to a user’s home directory!) to the system-wide Vim configuration `/etc/vim/vimrc`, you must

- either place the file `Vundle.vim` to a location that is valid system-wide (e.g. `/opt`, `/etc/vim`) *and* provide the path in `/etc/vim/vimrc`
- or ensure that the file `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` exists for *any* user, including root.

The home directory (`~`) for root is `/root`. So if the file `/root/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` does not exist on your machine, Vim cannot load it when processing your `/etc/vim/vimrc` as the root user.

> I got these errors while running `.vimrc`:
>
> ```
> # vim vimrc
> ```

This is likely not related to opening the `vimrc` file specifically, the problem impacts launching Vim as such because Vim reads its configuration files during that. It should happen even if you issue a plain `vim` command without any file.

By the way, be aware of each character of a filename. `vimrc` does not equal `.vimrc`, these are different files.